# Fetch xom from RES in odm 8.0.1

Tags: jrules, ibm-odm

I am currently using odm 8.0.1.I have a scenario in which I need to fetch the xom  from Res.I have fetched the ruleapp with res-fetch but not getting any options for the xom .

Actually my aim is to deploy the ruleapp from one server to another .If there is a other possible way for that do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the ruleapp archive directly to the Rule Execution Server of the other server. Once you logged in, go to the "Explorer" tab and click on "Deploy Rule App Archive".

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact that I need to use ant script for automation

Answer (score 0):

You could just use **res-jar** which retrieves a fully formed rule archive with all mandatory elements, and then use **res-deploy** to deploy it to your new server.

[ANT Commands for RES](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.5.1/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.ref.res/ant_tasks/con_ant_tasks_api_mappings.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few months old now, but a method that can work within ant that does what you need to do. It will use the fetch-all, but you can then pull the exact XOMs that you want. If you need more XOMs, you add more variables to it (e.g. TARGETXOM1, TARGETXOM2). This was included as a sample within the z/OS product on 8.7 and a white paper I helped write cover [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21690880&aid=1):

```
<target name="fetch-xom">
    <mkdir dir="${HBRWORKPATH}" /> 
       <res-fetch-all hostname="${FETCHHOSTNAME}"
              destfile="${HBRWORKPATH}/${HBRFILE}"           
              portnumber="${FETCHPORT}" webapp="res" 
              userid="${FETCHUSERID}" password="${FETCHPASSWORD}">
       </res-fetch-all>
    <unzip src="${HBRWORKPATH}/${HBRFILE}" dest="${HBRWORKPATH}">
        <patternset>
              <include name="${TARGETXOM}_${XOMVERSION}.zip" />
        </patternset> </unzip>
</target>

<!-- Step Two: Get the ruleapp from the repository -->
<target name="fetch-ruleapp">
    <res-fetch hostname="${FETCHHOSTNAME}"
    ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼destfile="${HBRWORKPATH}/${TARGETRULEAPP}.jar"
                          portnumber="${FETCHPORT}"
                         ￼userid="${FETCHUSERID}"    
                          password="${FETCHPASSWORD}"
                          ruleapp="${TARGETRULEAPP}" 
                          version="${TARGETRULEAPPVERSION}" />
</target>

<!-- Step Three: Deploy the ruleapp and XOM that was retrieved -->
<target name="deploywithxom">
    <res-deploy hostname="${DEPLOYHOSTNAME}" portnumber="${DEPLOYPORT}"
        webapp="${DEPLOYWEBAPP}" userid="${DEPLOYUSERID}" password="${DEPLOYPASSWORD}" file="${HBRWORKPATH}/${TARGETRULEAPP}.jar">
        <xompath rulesetpath="/${TARGETRULEAPP}/${TARGETRULESET}"> <fileset dir="${HBRWORKPATH}">
            <patternset>
                <include name="${TARGETXOM}_${XOMVERSION}.zip" />
            </patternset> </fileset>
        </xompath> </res-deploy>
    <!--Deploy the XOM  to the Target Rule Execution Server -->
    <res-deploy-xom hostname="${DEPLOYHOSTNAME}" 
                    portnumber="${DEPLOYPORT}" webapp="${DEPLOYWEBAPP}" 
                    userid="${DEPLOYUSERID}" password="${DEPLOYPASSWORD}" 
                    outputRulesetProperty="ruleset.managed.uris">
            <xompath>
            <fileset dir="${HBRWORKPATH}">
                <patternset>
                     <include name="${TARGETXOM}_${XOMVERSION}.zip" />
                </patternset> </fileset>
           </xompath> 
     </res-deploy-xom>
```

Let me know if you have questions!